# Remove only one border on input element and not effect the other borders

Tags: html, css, border

My intention for the script below (and also located at http://jsbin.com/enOxEya/1/) is just to remove the right border.

For FF, Chrome and IE, however, it makes the left and top border bold.

Furthermore, for FF, it removes the bottom border, and for Chrome and IE, it shades the bottom border.

See images for each browser (all browsers are fairly up to date)

Results from FF

[image: Results from FF]

Results from Chrome

[image: Results from Chrome]

Results from IE

[image: Results from IE]

Using border style none to just the top, bottom, and left border also produces unexpected results for all browsers.

How do I just remove a single border (i.e. the right one) without effecting the other three borders?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Boarders</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #input2 {border-right-style:none}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="input1" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="input2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have looks fine to me in chrome

Comment: @ExplosionPills.  Do both inputs look identical except for the right border?  I edited my original post to show images of what I see.

Comment: If I understand correct, why dont u put for input2 something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/sLAbb/

Comment: Thanks Szymon, Mohsen, and Sid.  Looks like all your answers require that style actively be placed on the remaining (3) borders.  Is it impossible to keep them as their default browser values?

Comment: I dont think so. But anyway its 1 line of code to do :). Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,it works fine

just replace

```
<style type='text/css'>
            #input2 {border-right-style:none}
        </style>
```

with this

```
<style type='text/css'>
            #input2 {border-style: solid none solid solid}
        </style>
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPNq6/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Boarders</title>
<style type='text/css'>
#input2 {
    border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
    border-right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input1" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="input2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer, but believe Sid's is a little better.